# Multiple MVC 4 Web Applications in the same Windows 2008 R2 Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, windows

Can I have multiple environments of the same MVC4 Web application in the same Windows 2008 R2 Web Edition server?

I would like to have:

- QA (Quality/Pre-production) environment - SQL-Server Database with QA MDF file
- Production environment -  SQL-Server Database with PRD MDF file
- Demonstration environment - SQL-Server Database with DEMO MDF file

Is it safe and reliable publishing from Visual Studio to each one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can deploy multiple instances of the app to the server. I would measure "safe" and "reliable" as aspects of the deployment process, not where the application is deployed to.

I try to keep my production and non-production environments separate, just in case anything goes wrong in testing I know it won't impact production. this separation can be physical (different hardware) or logical (same hardware, different configuration).

There are multiple factors to consider when deciding where to host production vs non-production. The main thing to consider is you don't want non-production environments competing for resources with the production application.

some other factors to consider are:

1. size the application
2. # of users
3. nature of the app (is the app critical to the success of the business, or a nice to have)
4. public vs. private application, etc.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It's a public application, and totally new, width low budget at the moment so I need to keep licensing costs to the minimum. Initially I hope visits but not a lot.